# Draft-js-plugins emoji select component - close popover after select emoji

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I'm using Draft-js-plugins emoji select component with react and I'm trying to close the popover upon selection of an emoji, I have read the documentation but didn't find a way to achieve that.

[Here](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/emoji) is the documentation and Live Examples.
You can see there that if you select emoji the popover stays open.

My code looks exactly as shown in the documentation.

Thanks is advance :)

Answer (score 1):

EmojiSelect has now the option `closeOnEmojiSelect`. If set to true it will close the popup after an emoji was selected.

```
<EmojiSelect closeOnEmojiSelect />
```